# LEFT JOIN only returning half the needed results

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions AS s
    LEFT JOIN submission_category AS sc ON s.submission_category = sc.sub_cat_id    
    JOIN hospitals      AS h  ON h.hospital_id        = sc.main_hospital_id
    JOIN products       AS p  ON p.product_id         = s.product_id
    JOIN product_group  AS pg ON pg.id                = p.product_group_id 
    JOIN progress_steps AS ps ON sc.approval_step     = ps.step_id
    WHERE s.approval_status='2' 
    AND sc.user_id='$mask5'
```

The problem is that sc has 3 rows and s has 6 rows. I need to return all six rows but currently it is only returning 3, one of each from s that corresponds to sc.

Based on the suggestion I am now trying:

```
SELECT * FROM submissions AS s
LEFT JOIN submission_category AS sc ON (s.submission_category = sc.sub_cat_id AND sc.user_id='$mask5' ) 
JOIN hospitals      AS h  ON h.hospital_id        = sc.main_hospital_id
JOIN products       AS p  ON p.product_id         = s.product_id
JOIN product_group  AS pg ON pg.id                = p.product_group_id 
JOIN progress_steps AS ps ON sc.approval_step     = ps.step_id
WHERE s.approval_status='2'
```

But still getting three rows, not six?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having columns of `LEFT JOIN`ed table[s] in `WHERE` "turns" `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER` (sc.user_id = '$mask5'  always returns `NULL` or false in case there is no corresponding row in submission_category ). Move `sc.user_id=...` into join condition :

```
....
LEFT JOIN submission_category AS sc ON (s.submission_category = sc.sub_cat_id AND 
 sc.user_id='$mask5' )
...
```

Comment: I tried the adjustment and updated the question. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dev Newb : The same issue with `[INNER] JOIN hospitals` and `progress_steps` ;it filters out records from resultset because it refers `sc`. They should be `LEFT JOIN`  as well. Sorry, I didn't notice it right of the bat.